# Problem getting the download url from firebase storage

Tags: javascript, download, firebase-storage

I'm trying to loop through files in my games folder on firebase and display them on the page like a list format.

```
// Create a reference under which you want to list
var listRef = firebase.storage().ref("games/");;

// Find all the prefixes and items.
listRef.listAll().then(function(res) {
  res.prefixes.forEach(function(folderRef) {
    // All the prefixes under listRef.
    // You may call listAll() recursively on them.
  });
  res.items.forEach(function(itemRef) {
    // All the items under listRef.
    console.log(itemRef)
    const p = document.createElement('a');
    p.textContent = itemRef.location.path;
    p.classList.add('col-lg-12');
    p.href = itemRef.getDownloadURL(); 
    console.log(p.href);
    

    document.getElementById('bar').appendChild(p);
    document.getElementById('bar').innerHTML+='<br />'

  });
}).catch(function(error) {
  // Uh-oh, an error occurred!
});
```

The problem is that I'm getting p.href = [object%20promise] instead of a download url to my file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [API documentation for getDownloadURL()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.storage.Reference#getdownloadurl) says that it returns a promise that resolves with the URL.  It does not return a URL directly. You're going to have to use this promise to get the URL in the same way that you're using the promise returned by `listAll()`.

```
itemRef.getDownloadURL().then(url => {
    console.log(url);
}
```

I suggest taking a good look at the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/download-files#download_data_via_url) for more information.

Comment: So you're saying nothing happened at all? That seems unlikely.

Comment: Well, the hyperlinks are gone

Comment: It sounds like you have a new problem that's different than the first one.  In that case, please post a new question with the updated code, and describe what isn't working the way you expect.

Comment: Works now, had to do with the storage reference